# Ionic Bluetooth serial SubscribeRawData Arduino

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, arduino, bluetooth, cordova-plugins

I have written this code to write to arduino and in turn read data that I receive from arduino, in the writing part, everything is fine but when I send a data from arduino to my app that data is broken down into several, if I send a "hello world "is randomly decomposed into:" h "" "" ello world ". this is my code:
**here is the home.ts**
i hope that you help me.
good day.

```
    constructor(private bluetoothSerial: BluetoothSerial, private alertcontroler: AlertController,private storage:Storage, private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef) {  this.bluetoothSerial.subscribeRawData().subscribe((dt) => {
    this.bluetoothSerial.read().then((dd) => {
      this.onDataReceive(dd);
      this.cdr.detectChanges(); 
      this.data=dd;
      console.log(this.data)
     });
    });
  }



onDataReceive(dd) {
    this.debug += "\n" + JSON.stringify(dd);
    this.cdr.detectChanges(); 
  }

  //write to arduino
  Dato1(){
    this.bluetoothSerial.write("envio desde aca");  
  }
```

**this is the arduino MEGA code:**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

String hola; 

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    
  if (Serial1.available()) {  
    hola=Serial1.readString(); 
    Serial.println(hola);
    Serial1.print("hola ¿como estas?");
  }
}
```